# silverlight wcf callback error try catch fails

Tags: wcf, silverlight, error-handling, callback

I am working on an application in Silverlight 5.  We use WCF for all of our network communication, and it mostly works well.  However, we have a couple of Virtual Machines that we use for testing where the app fails, tries to restart itself, fails, etc. in an endless loop.  I have added a lot of tracing code, and a lot of try catches, and I have it isolated all the way down to the line of code that is failing, but I still can't get an actual error message from the failure, just the crash.  Originally, it was failing on this line of WCF code:

```
return await Task<List<Instance>.Factory.FromAsync(Channel.BeginGetInstance, Channel.EndGetInstance, null);
```

In case it had something to do with the use of async/await, I went back to our old code with callbacks.  I still get the same failure, but now I can see the call to the WCF function completes successfully, but the log statement on the first line of the callback never happens, so it seems like its dying before or outside of the callback.

One other note, it appears the code we have in Application_UnhandledException is not firing, but the code in Application_Exit does run, I see that as the last line in the log file.

I tried to setup remote debugging, but I am unable to connect to the app before it crashes and recycles, so that didn't help either.

I also used TCPView to watch the network traffic, and it looks like communication is happening in both directions.

If anyone has any suggestions of anything else to try, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent 10 days chasing my tail on this before finally realizing my problem.  There was a bug in the error logging code.  It was generating an error, I was just not seeing it.  Once I realized that and got the error message, the actual underlying bug was fixed in about 5 minutes.  Good lesson though, never assume the underlying code is working, no matter how simple it is.